# How to refresh a view every second using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

this is a large question.

I would like to update a list of items (messages) in the body of a view every second.

The function will do this specific code:

1. My (new) data will be downloaded from my REST API
2. The data will be added to Core Data
3. The View (a simple list in my body) will be finally updated. (this is actually my problem)

**How to call a function every second in my View that will do this refresh?** I tried to use init() first, but I am locked after because the refresh of items combined with a timer was unstable in my part.

Thanks a lot for any path/lead that you could bring me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of this code belongs in your view.  It should be in a separate ObservableObject.  The view will subscribe to any @ObservedObject it owns and it will rebuild itself whenever that objects @Published properties change.

For example this code is an Observable object that starts a timer that starts a network request every second and assigns the result of those requests to the `@Published` myData property, which will cause the view that owns this Object to be rebuilt.  Its probably a very bad idea to fire a network request every second and assume it returns in the correct order, but if that's really what you want to do this code does it.

```
import Combine

class MyObserableObject: ObservableObject {
  @Published var myData: [Int] = []
  private var subscription: AnyCancellable?
  init() {
    subscription = Timer
      .TimerPublisher(interval: 1, runLoop: RunLoop.main, mode: .default)
      .map { _ -> AnyPublisher<[Int], Never> in
        URLSession
        .shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "somefakeurl.com")!)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: [Int].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .replaceError(with: [])
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      .switchToLatest()
      .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
      .assign(to: \.myData, on: self)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me more about « Its probably a very bad idea to fire a network request every second and assume it returns in the correct order » ? It’s a specific API. My request will ask directly in the get the lastest ID received in order to be in the correct order.

Comment: Network requests have no guaranteed return time and they don't necessarily take the same path to and from your client to the server so its actually possible that they will arrive out of order.  It may be better to instead fire a network request 1 second after the most recent response is received.